# How to filter data using javascript, jquery, or some other javascript framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, knockout.js

As an example, I have 3 check boxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="3">
```

I'm using PHP to send in some json, like so:

```
{'name': 'John Doe', 'title': 'CEO', 'filters': {'1':'2', '2':'3'}},
{'name': 'Jane Doe', 'title': 'COO', 'filters': {'1':'1', '2':'3'}},
{'name': 'Tim Doe', 'title': 'CFO', 'filters': {'1':'2'}}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to click on the checkboxes and only show records with the corresponding filters.  Is there something in jquery that would make that simple, or maybe a framework like Backbone or Knockout?  I've seen on example in Knockout, and it seemed needlessly complex... but maybe it IS more complex than I'm thinking it should be.

Thanks for any help, or being able to point me in the right direction.

*edit* - I'm totally open to reformatting the json, if that makes this easier.

Comment: As in `Array#filter`? Or are you having trouble with handling when the checkboxes are toggled?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit unsure of the filter object you send, but I guess it is the values you want to filter and not the keys. And I also guess that the response is an array with objects.

First I would create an array that the checkboxes add and remove values to. Showing of one input here, but all should point to the same array:

```
var filterArray = [];
var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
input.value = "1";
input.onclick = function() {
    if (this.checked)
        filterArray.push(this.value); // Add value to array
    else
        filterArray.splice(filterArray.indexOf(this.value), 1); // Remove value from Array
    filterPersons(); // Run the filter function

}
```

Then I would run something like this:

```
function filterPersons() {
    var persons = phpResponse;
    var result = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < persons.length; x++) {
        var personFilters = persons[x].filters;
        for (var filter in personFilters) {
            if (personFilters.hasOwnProperty(filter) && filterArray.indexOf(personFilters[filter]) >= 0) // Check if value is in filterArray
                result.push(persons[x]); // Add person to a result array
        }

        displayResult(result); // Display the result somewhere

    }
```

This would also make it work "on the fly", when you click the checkboxes.

Comment: Yes, the values are what I'm looking to filter.  Thanks, this might get me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on to ExtJS. It has the object "store", which is able to store structured data and allow to do manipulations with it, like sorting, filtering, querying.
For example your task could be resolved like that:

```
Ext.application({
name: 'HelloExt',
launch: function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        storeId:'UsersStore',
        model: 'User',
        fields: [ 'id', 'name', 'title', 'filter1', 'filter2', 'filter3' ],
        data: [
            { name: 'Ed',    title: 'CEO', filter1: true, filter2: false, filter3: true },
            { name: 'Tommy', title: 'CTO', filter1: false, filter2: false, filter3: false },
            { name: 'Aaron', title: 'COO', filter1: true, filter2: true, filter3: true },
            { name: 'Jamie', title: 'CFO', filter1: true, filter2: true, filter3: false }
        ]
    });

    function filterStore() {
        var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('UsersStore');
        store.clearFilter();
        store.filter([
            { property: 'filter1', value: Ext.getCmp('Filter1CB').getValue() },
            { property: 'filter2', value: Ext.getCmp('Filter2CB').getValue() },
            { property: 'filter3', value: Ext.getCmp('Filter3CB').getValue() }
        ]);
    }

    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout: 'vbox',
        layoutConfig: {
            vbox: {
                align: 'stretch'
            }
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                border: false,
                padding: 10,
                items: {
                    flex: 1,
                    xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                    items: [
                        { fieldLabel: 'Filter1', xtype: 'checkbox', id: 'Filter1CB', handler: filterStore },
                        { fieldLabel: 'Filter2', xtype: 'checkbox', id: 'Filter2CB', handler: filterStore },
                        { fieldLabel: 'Filter3', xtype: 'checkbox', id: 'Filter3CB', handler: filterStore }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                flex: 1,
                xtype: 'gridpanel',
                title: 'Users',
                store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('UsersStore'),
                columns: [
                    { header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' },
                    { header: 'Title', dataIndex: 'title' }
                ]
            }
        ]
    });
}
```

});

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q55ym/1/

Answer (score -1):

You mean loop through the JSON to find only the entries with the filter?
First, change filters in the JSON to `'filters':'1'` or `'filters':'12'` or `'filters':'13'` or whatever. Just put the filters into 1 string.

Then use this:

```
function filter(){
  var loadedJSON;  // load the json from php here,
                   //sort 'filter' by number from smallest to largest
                   //(so '312' becomes '123')

  for(var i in loadedJSON){
    String check="";

    if($("checkbox[name='filter[]'][value='1']").is(":checked"))check="1";
    if($("checkbox[name='filter[]'][value='2']").is(":checked"))check+="2";
    if($("checkbox[name='filter[]'][value='3']").is(":checked"))check+="3";

    if(i.filters.indexOf(check)>-1) // passed filters
  }
}
```

I used jquery to determine if the checkboxes are checked, but you could also do `document.getElementsByName('filter[]')[0].checked`